# Is there a better way to input data from one excel sheet into a table on another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that functions as an "input sheet". Users will go in and type things like their name and phone number etc into specific cells. As shown below.

[image: Image 1]
,

From there I have code that will store the data from the cell into a new table row.

`Set NewTableRow = DatabaseTable.ListRows.Add
 NewTableRow.Range(1, 1).Value = InputSheet.Range("D5").Value
 NewTableRow.Range(1, 2).Value = InputSheet.Range("I5").Value`

Unfortunately if I insert a row or move a cell on the input sheet I am forced to change potentially hundreds of lines of code every time, which can be very time consuming as there are over 135 inputs on this sheet. Is there a better way I could be doing this?

Comment: A userform is probably the way to go for the data entry. If there is a lot of data and it is feasible moving to access might be better.

Comment: Or match the input to the particular list column it's supposed to go into.

Comment: Are the 135 inputs in groups like ADDRESS has 5 inputs, MANAGER has 2 etc. If so how many groups ?

Comment: Some are in groups while others aren't (probably about 20 groups total). I'm trying to use the labels to act as a named range. For example, have the code search for the label "name" then assign the text in the box to the right to a string variable. Not sure how much this will slow things down though. @CDP1802

Comment: OK, In that case you could define 20 constant (1 for each group) with the cell reference for a corner of that group. Then use .offsets() from that point for the inputs in that group. You have to maintain the constants but there should be minimal code changes. Alternative use a hidden column to the right of the input to store the table column it refers to.

Comment: Wow both of those ideas would actually work great! Might need to make a few tweaks for some of the more dynamic areas but better than what I was doing. Thanks! @CDP1802

Comment: Your welcome, also look at using [WITH .. END WITH blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement), it will save you loads of typing.:)